# What are the benefits or advantages of creating a navigation menu out of json data and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, navigation

What are the benefits or advantages of creating a navigation menu out of json data and javascript? VS. creating a regular navigation menu using just html and css.

Comment: the disadvantage is that search engines might not see js, but they always see hard-coded links. css is not a factor, and you can use JS to spruce up html navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is easier to render your menu using javascript on client-side. Of course JSON would be the best option for this. But it is highly depends on what the app are you developing.

As dandavis told, your menu control might not be indexed properly if it is not rendered by the server using html.

So, if your menu is static, go ahead and implement it using HTML5 navigation tags. If it is not, you have at least 2 options:

- render your menu using server-side and get it indexed properly
- use JSON and Javascript, take advantage of flexible DOM manipulations and JSON nesting(if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

as dandavis stated - SEO can be a problem - spiders not seing navigation or not seing whole of it (could be somehow solved with  but there hard-links must be used, so again not so well for bots...

On the other hand - and maybe in intranet portals (SEO not an issue) - that method brings a lot of freedom in the front-end - generating menues on the fly,...

My last thought would be - generate navigation in back-end (plain HTML  and also manipulate it there - so you get SEO proofed and flexible at the same time.